# How do I resolve the error "Unable to get setup.ini from <http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports/>"?

Tags: cygwin

I have a running cygwin installation and I am following steps at http://cygwinports.org/.

I run in the cygwin console

```
$ wget http://cygwin.com/setup.exe -O /tmp/setup.exe
$ /tmp/setup.exe -K http://cygwinports.org/ports.gpg
```

I add ftp://ftp.cygwinports.org/pub/cygwinports as additional source (along with an existing one), but get error dialogue

`Unable to get setup.ini from <http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports/>`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I actually had http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports as source -- from a previous attempt, since that is what http://cygwinports.org/ suggests:

```
Mirrors are available by instead entering http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports as the User URL.
```

The relevant part of the console output was:

```
get_url_to_membuf http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports//setup.bz2
getUrlToStream http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports//setup.bz2
getUrlToStream failed!
get_url_to_membuf failed!
get_url_to_membuf http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports//setup.bz2.sig
getUrlToStream http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports//setup.bz2.sig
getUrlToStream failed!
get_url_to_membuf failed!
get_url_to_membuf http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports//setup.ini
getUrlToStream http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports//setup.ini
getUrlToStream failed!
get_url_to_membuf failed!
get_url_to_membuf http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports//setup.ini.sig
getUrlToStream http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports//setup.ini.sig
getUrlToStream failed!
get_url_to_membuf failed!
mbox note: Unable to get setup.ini from <http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports/>
```

After removing the sourceforge URL, the ftp://ftp.cygwinports.org/pub/cygwinports URI was used fine. It is just very slow (130kb/s), so having ports downloaded from sf.net would be much better.

Comment: It sounds like you may have http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports/ configured as a package source, which I wouldn't do -- what mirrors are you using? What output is setup.exe generating on your console? Add this info to your question and I might be able to answer, thanks --

Comment: @AaronMiller: Thanks, I edited the post, hopefully it contains everything relevant now.

Comment: The Sourceforge http:// mirror doesn't seem to work the way the Cygwin Ports folks intend it to; the whole Sourceforge download system, mirror selector and all, is involved there. I'd take that up with them, but in the meantime, it sounds like using the FTP mirror has got you going, if not as quickly as would be ideal.

Comment: I just ran into the "unable to get setup.ini" error, and had to change from `setup.exe` to `setup-x86.exe`.

Comment: I think this question is duplicated, refer to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496333/installing-cygwin-setup-ini-missing-from-http-mirrors-kernel-org]